# Ordering line segments consisting of two points

Tags: c++, graphics, operators, line

How would I implement a operator< for line segments that consist of a start and a end Point. I want to insert the line segments into a map so the order doesn't need to be semantic, but it should work for all cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Order everything lexicographically:

```
struct Point { int x; int y; };

bool operator<(Point const & a, Point const & b)
{
    return (a.x < b.x) || (!(b.x < a.x) && (a.y < b.y));
}
```

Or use the ready made comparator from `tuple`:

```
#include <tuple>

// ...

return std::tie(a.x, a.y) < std::tie(b.x, b.y);
```

Or actually use a `std::tuple<int, int>` for your points and do nothing at all!

Then, do the same for the lines:

```
struct LineSegment { Point x; Point y; };

// repeat same code as above, e.g.

bool operator<(LineSegment const & a, LineSegment const & b)
{
    return std::tie(a.x, a.y) < std::tie(b.x, b.y);
}
```

To repeat, the no-work-at-all solution just uses tuples all the way:

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int> Point;
typedef std::tuple<Point, Point> LineSegment;
// everything "just works"
```

Comment: I want to order line segments with two points and not just single points.

Comment: @funkysash: Sorry, I misread that... Just apply this idea recursively to `struct Line { Point x; Point y; };`. Exact same code.